# How to use a Boolean in Javascript Constructors?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, boolean

I have a constructor, and I would like to do some things that I can't seem to get to work.

- I would like to force a boolean with the planet argument. I could use form validation to format it manually, but it's bugging me that I can't figure out how to do it in JS.
- I would like to insert a date  in this constructor. Again, I could take care of it on the front end, but I want to handle it here.

  ```
  var telescope = [];

  function newStar(name, color, planet) {
      this.name = name
      this.color = color
      this.planet = planet // interpreted as "Is a planet?" true/false
      telescope.push(this)
  }
  var a = new newStar("sol", "yellow", false)
  var b = new newStar("mars", "red", true)
  console.log(telescope)
  ```

Comment: Ehm, what? Try explaining exactly what you're trying to do ?

Comment: You do know that javascript is ALL front end, right? (with the exception of NodeJS)

Comment: @RUJordan Yes, I understand that JS is frontend. I"m not looking to implement the code into a full-blown project. I'm looking to use this by itself.

Comment: @adeneo I'm looking to tell JS to EXPECT a boolean, not simply be able to understand one (I'm not even sure that this is technically possible without some external structure/resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the datatype of a variable in ECMAScript (commonly known as JavaScript) you can do that like this:

```
if (typeof planet !== 'boolean') {
    throw TypeError('planet should be Boolean');
}
// do something here
```

For "I would like to insert a date in this model", not sure what you are asking?

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, there is no way to tell the conbstructor itself that a value must be of a certain type. If you're looking for something specific, you would just write an if statement to check for it. Correct?

Comment: Yes, In ECMAScript (commonly known as JavaScript) you can't restrict the values of a variable to be of a certain type, as it is a dynamically typed language.

Comment: Thank you, sir. You are a Kundu and a scholar ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add date in it like;

```
var telescope = [];

function newStar(name, color, planet) {
    this.name = name
    this.color = color
    this.planet = planet // interpreted as "Is a planet?" true/false
    this.create_date = new Date();
    telescope.push(this)
}
var a = new newStar("sol", "yellow", false)
var b = new newStar("mars", "red", true)
console.log(telescope)
```

However I don't understand first. Could you explain what do you want?

Comment: For the date portion, this was exactly what I was looking for. I kept trying to use Date() while calling the function, thinking it wouldn't work inside the constructor. Thanks!